# Database query vs string comparison performance

Tags: c#, string, performance, comparison, query-optimization

I am working on a .NET application where we perform many queries on our remote database.

There is a string, which could be several paragraphs long, that the user has the ability to change.

Right now, we are taking that string and updating it in our database regardless of whether the string was changed or not.

I am thinking about saving the string when we retrieve it from the database and comparing it to what the client returns. If the strings are the same, I don't do a database query, and if they are different I would do a query.

Since the string could be several paragraphs long, doing string comparison could take quite a long time and saving the string could also take up space. Am I better off keeping the system as it is or should I do a string comparison to determine if I need to do a database update?

Comment: `dbString == inputString` isn't going to take `quite a long time` to compare

Comment: Why not just track whether or not the string was changed (e.g. in the property setter) instead of doing a compare before the update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since string comparisons on the client side are done in memory, and because you do not need to search for the old string, checking equality would run very quickly. It would also happen in a naturally distributed way, because each client would do its own comparison.

In contrast, sending a string to the server would be slow, because network operations are inevitably slower than linear-time in-memory operations on the same data. Additionally, all updates would happen on a single server, increasing the load on a centralized component of your system.

If the string remains unchanged in a significant number of cases, you would be better off doing a comparison in memory to reduce the number of round-trips.

If, on the other hand, the string rarely remains unchanged, you could simplify the code by dropping this optimization.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful answer!